# In hibernate criteria multiple join results are duplicate

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I am getting multiple data through Criteria API.

My Association mapping in entity is

```
public class UserGroupEntity{

    private Set<UserEntity> users = new TreeSet<>();
    private List<DocumentEntity> documents = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
        name="FG_DDA_User__UserGroup", 
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="usergroup_id", nullable=false),},       
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)})
    public Set<UserEntity> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<UserEntity> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    /**
     * @return the documents
     */
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
        name="FG_DDA_Document__UserGroup", 
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="usergroup_id", nullable=false),}, 
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="document_id",nullable=false)})
    public List<DocumentEntity> getDocuments() {
        return documents;
    }
}
```

I am getting data from criteria. code is

```
Criterion criterian = Restrictions.idEq(id);
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(getPersistentClass());
criteria.add(criterian);
if(eagerFetchColumn != null){
    for (String string : eagerFetchColumn) {
        criteria.setFetchMode(string, FetchMode.JOIN);
    }
    criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
}
List<UserGroupEntity> result = (List<UserGroupEntity>)criteria.list();
if (result.size() == 1) {
    return result.iterator().next();
}
if (result.size() == 0) {
    return null;
}
throw new RuntimeException("Found more than one object with the given ID, verify integrity of you data");
```

I am getting unique data for UserGroupEntity, **users** is also unique because it is Set. But **documents** are multiple because it is list and this is my problem. Can i also receive unique **documents** through multiple join in list.

Query:

```
SELECT t_.id          AS a,
  t_.name             AS b,
  du_.usergroup_id    AS c,
  d_.id               AS d,
  d_.id               AS e,
  d_.activeVersion_id AS f,
  d_.name             AS g,
  uu_.usergroup_id    AS h,
  u_.id               AS i,
  u_.id               AS j,
  u_.name             AS k,
  u_.password         AS l,
  u_.role_id          AS m,
  u_.toc_code         AS n,
  u_.email_id         AS o,
  u_.isValid          AS p
FROM dbo.FG_DDA_UserGroup t_
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.FG_DDA_Document__UserGroup du_ ON t_.id=du_.usergroup_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.FG_DDA_Document d_ ON du_.document_id=d_.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.FG_DDA_User__UserGroup uu_ ON t_.id=uu_.usergroup_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.FG_DDA_User u_ ON uu_.user_id=u_.id
WHERE t_.id   = ?
```

Comment: Could you show SQL generated by Hibernate?

Comment: Hibernate: select t_.id as a, t_.name as b, du_.usergroup_id as c, d_.id as d, d_.id as e, d_.activeVersion_id as f, d_.name as g, uu_.usergroup_id as h, u_.id as i, u_.id as j, u_.name as k, u_.password as l, u_.role_id as m, u_.toc_code as n, u_.email_id as o, u_.isValid as p from dbo.FG_DDA_UserGroup t_ left outer join dbo.FG_DDA_Document__UserGroup du_ on t_.id=du_.usergroup_id left outer join dbo.FG_DDA_Document d_ on du_.document_id=d_.id left outer join dbo.FG_DDA_User__UserGroup uu_ on t_.id=uu_.usergroup_id left outer join dbo.FG_DDA_User u_ on uu_.user_id=u_.id  where t_.id = ?

Comment: It looks to me that you want to load UserGroupEntity. Why you use criteria instead of plain `org.hibernate.Session#get`

Comment: Thanks Michaldo..I can use org.hibernate.Session#get but I want to use Criteria API for all queries. If It is possible using Criteria API then it will be good. Because i will learn something new..

Comment: I think you learnt that Criteria API is wrong tool. Basically, Criteria API produce SQL, SQL produce Cartesian product and finally you see multiplication. To load UserGroupEntity 2 SQL must called, one for users and second for documents. Best way to load is trust to Hibernate Session#get